# How to get session data in Laravel Dusk?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-dusk

I was wondering why we cannot get the session data when testing with Laravel Dusk ?

In any controller in Laravel we can get session data with `Session::get('data');`

When we are running a Laravel Dusk test, we take a screenshot with the phpdebugbarr opened (very usefull). We can see on the screenshot that the session is correctly filled with our data, but if we call `Session::all();` juste after `browser->screenshot()` then it return an empty array !

Is it even possible to get the session with Dusk ? I don't find any mention of session managing with Dusk on Google.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Laravel Dusk operates on a separate browser instance, meaning it doesn't share the same session as your Laravel application. This isolation is intentional to ensure test independence and prevent unintended interactions between different test cases.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost it's better to say that sessions are serverside concepts and are different than cookies.
As Laravel defined Dusk:

> Laravel Dusk provides an expressive, easy-to-use browser automation
> and testing API.

It means that in the Dusk browser instance, you are reaching the end level of seeing results just by acting as an automation system or as a user.
It means that in the rendered part you can access only front-side parts but can't access backend things.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing session data directly during tests is challenging due to the architecture of Dusk because its browser-based testing. Dusk operates separately from your Laravel application's server-side processes, including session management.

It works as if how an external browser would, ie doesn't have direct access to server-side data like the session. To test specific functionalities that involve session data, you may need to check the changes on a browser leve, like changes in the displayed data or UI , rather than trying to access the session data directly. For more complex actions, indirect methods like API calls or database queries might be necessary to inspect the session state.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Dusk uses a separate testing environment, and as a result, it doesn't share the same session as your regular application. However, it is possible to access the session data in your Dusk tests.

To address this issue, you can create a helper function that retrieves the session data directly from the session storage. This way, you can access the session data within your Dusk tests.

This is an example of how to create such a helper function and use it in your Dusk tests.

1. Create a helper function to retrieve session data:

```php
// In your test helpers file (e.g., tests/DuskTestCase.php)
function getSessionData($key = null) {
    $sessionFilePath = storage_path('framework/sessions/' . session()->getId());
    
    if (file_exists($sessionFilePath)) {
        $sessionData = unserialize(file_get_contents($sessionFilePath));
        
        if ($key !== null) {
            return data_get($sessionData, $key);
        } else {
            return $sessionData;
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

2. Use the helper function in your Dusk test:

```php
// In your Dusk test
public function testSessionData() {
    $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/your-page')
            ->screenshot('session_data_screenshot');

        // Retrieve session data using the helper function
        $sessionData = getSessionData();
        
        // Use the retrieved session data as needed
        // For example:
        $userData = data_get($sessionData, 'user');
        $this->assertEquals('John Doe', $userData['name']);
    });
}
```

In this example, the `getSessionData` helper function reads the session file directly and returns the session data. You can then use this helper function in your Dusk tests to access the session data and perform assertions based on the retrieved data.

Remember to replace `/your-page` with the actual URL of the page you want to visit in your Dusk test.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).